# Responsive divs issue - one div fixed, second responsive with fixed margin

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to understand the case with responsive divs but I've got one problem.

As long as whole stuff is about 100% div's width it's not a big deal. But I find it difficult to add some additional features.

Here's my tiny fiddle:

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/yqh31d7v/][1]
```

The effect I'd like to gain is to fix sidebar's width (unless I define it to not) and shrink only blue div maintaing fixed margin-left at 20px.

I was trying to set width with % but it is not holding correct margin-left all the time.

So no matter what the browser width is I want to keep 300px sidebar width 20px margin left and keep blue div responsive from 0 to 700px.

P.S. I've checked some previous topics including ie. this fiddle

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/FXk4x/10/][2]
```

But adding left:20px; or margin-left:20px doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have this css at the bottom:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {

    #sidebar {
        float:left;
        margin-left:0px;
        width:300px;
    }
}
```

This is telling the browser that if the window is 850px or less then apply these rules (`margin-left:0px;`). So your css is working, but your viewing in the wrong screen widths to see the `margin-left:20px;` occur. Check these two examples:

Your exact code but in full screen (you will see the 20px margin if your screen width is higher than 850px):
https://jsfiddle.net/yqh31d7v/embedded/result/

Using a max width of 50px for the media query:
https://jsfiddle.net/yqh31d7v/1/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have figured it out.

If you want to mix fixed and responsive floating divs you need to change position of fixed one to absolute.

I'ce updated the previous fiddle, it's more or less like this:

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/yqh31d7v/][1]
```